# Code printing the incorrect output (Python problem)

Tags: python

My code is not printing the correct result for the test case

```
2 6
1 alex
1 Alex
2 sam
1 alix
1 Alix
2 caM
```

properly as it should result in "alex, sam", yet it results in "alex, Alex" (After reading the following instructions youll understand why). Was hoping I can get some insight as to what is wrong with my code.

**Exercise:** Dan’s recently announced that he’s teaching n top-secret courses next semester.
Instead of enrolling in them through ACORN, students need to email Dan to
express their interests. These courses are numbered from 1 to n in some arbitrary
order.
In particular, if a student named s is interested in taking a course c, they need to
send an email to Dan containing the message c s. Note that if a student is
interested in taking multiple courses, they need to send multiple emails, one per
course.
Upon receiving a message c s, Dan looks at the list of students already enrolled in
course c. If there’s already a student on the list whose name is too similar to s,
Dan assumes s is the same student and ignores the message. Otherwise, he
enrolls s in the course.
Dan considers two names too similar if and only if they have the same length and
differ in at most one letter(note that “a” and “A” are considered the same letter).
For example, “Josh” and “Josh” are too similar. “Sam” and “CaM” are too similar
as well. However, neither “Max” and “Cat” nor “Ann” and “Anne” are too similar.
Dan has a lot of students and teaches a lot of courses. Consequently, it would take
him forever to process the messages sent by the students one-by-one manually.
Instead, he’s asking you to help him out by writing a program that takes in the
messages as the input and outputs, for every course, the list of the students
enrolled in that course in the order of their enrolments.

**My code thus far**:

```
u = input()
u, w = u.split()
courses = int(u)
students = int(w)
names = []
classes = []

for i in range(students):
    names_input = input()
    selection = names_input.split()
    course_num = selection[0]
    student_name = selection[1]

    if course_num not in classes:
        classes.append(course_num)
        names.append(student_name)
    else:
        if student_name not in names:
            names.append(student_name)

    print(classes)
    print(names)

for i in range(0, len(classes)):
    print(names[i])
```

[image: Image of the question]

image of the question here as well [Question in a screenshot, if its easier to read feel free to see it here as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWdcT.png)

Comment: Your code doesn't check whether names are "too similar". It only checks whether the exact name has already been used. (among multiple other problems)

Comment: Mind enlightening on those other problems? debugging it and showing me where i went wrong would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Try fixing the problem I've pointed out. Then if it still doesn't work you can try posting another question. But I suggest trying it yourself first. And see [ask] to produce a better question. It is too broad for Stackoverflow as it is now